# Installing .NET 3.5 under ubuntu 11

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono-framework

I am trying to install the .net 2.5 framework in a ubuntu box.

I am following the instructions from these links:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10166

After I start the

```
`bash winetricks dotnet35 `
```

although the 2.0 .net is installed successfully my 3.0 installation fails giving me an error encountered screen which has a link to some microsoft owned page for troubleshouting general .net installation issues...

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should post your question within the Wine community / forum, where you'll find more likely a solution

Answer (score 1):

Appdb says "The installer stop works.". It just doesn't work. You should use Mono if you want to run .net framework based apps.